# python writing a decorator with class

Tags: python, decorator, mutable

here is my effort in writing a helper decorator module:

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

import time
def timer(func):
    def timed(*args, **kwargs):
        init = time.clock()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        print (time.clock()-init)*1000, 'ms'

        return result    
    return timed

class memo(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        self.memo = {}
        self.memohit = 0   

    def memoizedf(self, *args):
        key = tuple(args)
        print key
        lookup = self.memo.setdefault(key, None)
        if lookup:
            self.memohit += 1 
            return lookup

        result = self.func(*args)
        self.memo[key]=result
        return result

    def __call__(self, *args):
        return self.memoizedf(*args)
```

so, usage:

```
@timer
def foo():
    print 'foo'

'foo'
00023.1231203879 ms


@memo
def bar(fooobject):
    print fooobject
```

the problem comes here:

```
>>bar({'foo':'bar'})

traceback : ...........
    lookup = self.memo.setdefault(key, None)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

every input of list, dict, or other mutable from collections would invoke such error.
I tried tupling all args, but apparently this didn't help. How should I rewrite my code in order to have my decorator to work with any(well, just dict, list, tuple, set, int, string... would be ok) kind of input?

Comment: there are many memoize recipes on the internet and Python 3.2+ comes with `functools.lru_cache`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669391/python-anyone-have-a-memoizing-decorator-that-can-handle-unhashable-arguments

Comment: you just couldn't use a mutable object for a key in a dict. Maybe you could use `str` to get a hashable representation of the object.

Comment: Are you only trying to pass one argument?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to serialize the mutable arguments before hashing, for example using the [pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) module. The contents of any dict, list, or similar in the function arguments have to be picklable, otherwise a `PicklingError` will be raised. In your definition of `memoizedf`, you could use this code:

```
key = pickle.dumps((args,kwargs))
lookup = self.memo.setdefault(key, None)
```

A lot of objects are picklable, but not hashable, so this should extend the class of arguments that you can deal with significantly.

Answer (score -1):

This will do the trick:

```
key = str(tuple(args))
```

Comment: The `str()` function is generally not guaranteed to return a useful result for memoizing objects.