# How to create an object collection proxy in Python?

Tags: python, object, collections, proxy

I'm trying to create an object collection proxy, which could do something like this:

```
class A:
    def do_something():
        # ...

class B:
    def get_a():
        return A()

class Proxy:
    ?

collection = [B(), B()]
proxy = Proxy(collection)

proxy.get_a().do_something()
# ^ for each B in collection get_a() and do_something()
```

What would be the best architecture / strategy for achieving this?

The key question, I guess is, how to cache the result of get_a() so I can then proxy do_something()

N.B. I don't expect `proxy.get_a().do_something()` to return anything sensible, it's only supposed to do things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple enough... you may want to adapt it to do some more checking

```
class A(object):
    def do_something(self):
        print id(self), "called"

class B(object):
    def get_a(self):
        return A()

class Proxy(object):
    def __init__(self, objs):
        self._objs = objs

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        def func(*args, **kwargs):
            return Proxy([getattr(o, name)(*args, **kwargs) for o in self._objs])
        return func

collection = [B(), B()]

proxy = Proxy(collection)
proxy.get_a().do_something()
```

Results in:

```
4455571152 called
4455571216 called
```

Comment: That doesn't deal with caching calls to `B.get_a()` though (I first overlooked that requirement as well). But your class based approach to proxying and the memoization techniques in my answer should provide @Alex with everything he needs :)

Comment: Actually he doesn't want to cache it I think. He simply meant how can he store the result of the call to get_A until do_something is called.

Comment: Lukas, Garet, thanks that's what I was after. Garet, you're right, I just wanted to pipe it through so I can "chain" the next call in my code nicely.

Answer (score 2):

The most pythonic way of going about this would probably be a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
results = [b.get_a().do_something() for b in collection]
```

If you want to cache calls to `B.get_a()`, you can use [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). A simple way of doing memoization yourself could look like this:

```
cache = None

# ...

class B:
    def get_a(self):
        global cache
        if cache is None:
            cache = A()
        return cache
```

If you want to use caching in multiple places, you'll need to cache results based on keys in order to distinguish them, and for convenience's sake write a [decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1594484/1599111) that you can simply wrap functions with whose results you want to cache.

A good example of this is found in *Python Algorithms: Mastering Basic Algorithms in the Python Language* (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669391/python-anyone-have-a-memoizing-decorator-that-can-handle-unhashable-arguments)). Modified for your case, to not use the function arguments but the function name as cache key, it would look like this:

```
from functools import wraps

def memoize(func):
    cache = {}
    key = func.__name__
    @ wraps(func)
    def wrap(*args):
        if key not in cache:
            cache[key] = func(*args)
        return cache[key]
    return wrap

class A:
    def do_something(self):
        return 1

class B:
    @memoize
    def get_a(self):
        print "B.get_a() was called"
        return A()


collection = [B(), B()]

results = [b.get_a().do_something() for b in collection]
print results
```

Output:

```
B.get_a() was called
[1, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks, Lukas. Probably it wasn't clear from the question I was looking for a class-based way of doing this, as I need to provide an interface like myclass.get_a().do_something() which would iterate over it's own collection, but your answer points me in some direction, so I'll keep digging.