# Python - how do I memoize a partial object?

Tags: python, memoization, functools

I have a set of functions that take integers and functions as arguments. I'd like to memoize them.

I know that using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669391/python-anyone-have-a-memoizing-decorator-that-can-handle-unhashable-arguments), I could use `pickle` to encode both sets of arguments and memoize the encoded values. In this particular use case, however, the function arguments are large and constant, and I'd rather not take up the `lru_cache` space with a function argument that, in the course of a program run, never changes.

Is there a way for me to memoize a partial function, where I've fixed the function arguments and have received a partial object that takes only hashable arguments? I can't figure out how to use the `functools.lru_cache` decorator as a function.

Here's what I've tried on a toy example. It doesn't work; the binomial tree still revisits nodes.

```
import functools
import logging


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)


def binomial_tree(x, y, fn):
    logging.debug(f"binomial_tree({x}, {y})")
    """Note: this does not recombine, and we can't memoize function."""
    if x == 10:
        return fn(x, y)
    else:
        return 0.5 * binomial_tree(x + 1, y, fn) + 0.5 * binomial_tree(x + 1, y + 1, fn)


def memoize_fn(fn):
    @functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return inner

memoized_binomial_tree = memoize_fn(functools.partial(binomial_tree, fn=lambda x, y: 10 * x * y))
print(memoized_binomial_tree(0, 0))
```

Comment: The problem here is that your memoization of partial object doesn't affect the two calls `binomial_tree(x + 1, y, fn)` and `binomial_tree(x + 1, y + 1, fn)`.

Comment: Right. I think I I'd be fine if I just memoized `binomial_tree`. But I don't want to in this instance.

Comment: The function argument really never changes during a program run? It may be a stupid question but what's the point of making a partial instead of using a class or a global variable for the function? Or am I taking the toy example too serious?

Comment: Library where I want to pass to select amongst multiple different versions of `fn`. But yes, changing a global would work. I just dont like globals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a way to memoize your toy example with `binomial_tree` without encoding and memoizing function arguments:

```
import functools
import logging


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)


def create_binomial_tree(fn):
    @functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)
    def binomial_tree(x, y):
        logging.debug(f"binomial_tree({x}, {y})")
        if x == 10:
            return fn(x, y)
        else:
            return 0.5 * binomial_tree(x + 1, y) + 0.5 * binomial_tree(x + 1, y + 1)
    return binomial_tree


memoized_binomial_tree = create_binomial_tree(fn=lambda x, y: 10 * x * y)
print(memoized_binomial_tree(0, 0))
```

Maybe it can be applicable in your real use case?

Comment: Ok, so I mimic partial with closure but insert the caching in between. That works.